# Sign in to Hidden local user

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have installed windows 10 on a Computer Lab PC, and the starting account was Local account, my supervisor asked me to Hide the local account that was first created because it’s an Admin by default and let a student sign in with his school email address, but Now I have to install some programs and it asks me to sign in as admin of course, while I can’t sign in from the lock screen because the admin is hidden, and I cannot show it because The student school Email doesn’t have access to do that ! So is there is a command to write or a name when it prompts me to sign in as Administrator?
What I tried:

1. Someone told me you can write”./username” and the password but it didn’t work, while I know the username and the PC Name too.
2. Tried to show the default Administrator account from the Computer Management window but I didn’t have access to do that.

Sorry for the long text. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching online for 2 hours, the problem was The command that the person told me is wrong, it should be .\username to sign in to a hidden local account. Not ./username.